# Powershell for scripting large analysis runs

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm completely new to Powershell and I know that a number of people use it to automate tasks much in the way bash and c-shell programming is done in *NIX.  I've successfully recompiled some ancient analysis software written in FORTRAN that takes individual input files.  I now need to somehow run just under 1000 cases with only slightly varied input files.  The analysis software writes intermediate files, so for concurrent runs, every run has to be within a different directory.  Each case can take up to 40 minutes to solve, so individually running these will take a lot of time and be prone to error.

So now for the question, can Powershell automate this and is there some similar script out there that I can modify to do it?

The automation would need to do the following (as I see it):

1. Take in an input file with the various runs that have to be run
2. Create a subdirectory relative to the run name/number
3. Save a version of the input files with the variables switched in the subdirectory
4. Run the analysis software in the subdirectory
5. Look at standard/error output of analysis software to confirm it was successful
6. Append to a file success or failure of a run
7. Ideally would be able to run up to some number of analyses concurrently (4-6 for my machine)
8. If IT reboots the machine (as they do whenever they choose), I'd like to be able to restart where it left off, though I expect the loss of anything that the analysis software was running during the forced reboot.

I've tried recompiling the software with vectorization and automated parallelization and on the tested cases, the convergence time was only minimally reduced, so it is safe to assume that this is effectively single threaded.

Comment: Sure, that can be done with PowerShell. It's a full-featured scripting language and can automate far more complex things than what you've described. There's no default script, you'd have to write one.

Comment: By default script, I'm asking if there is something that someone has posted that is similar enough that I can start with that.  Having to do it without anything other than book resources may take me as long as the time required to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell has lots of familiar aliases for Unix users. ls, cat, cp etc are implemented as aliases to native Powershell commands. The commands are not case sensitive. What's more, you can search help even with alias' name. That is,

`man ls <=> get-help get-childitem`

```
apropos <=> get-help <keyword>
get-help loop
about_Break
about_Continue
about_do
about_For
about_Foreach
about_Language_Keywords
...
```

This should help converting an existing script. For the rest, I'll give some hints as the description is somewhat vague.

Get-Content is used to read file contents into a variable: `$myVar = cat c:\some\file.txt`.

Directory creation is just `md`.

Capturing exe output is done by assigning to a variable: `$exeOutput = c:\myApp.exe`

Adding stuff to a file is `Add-Content`.

[Background jobs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/03/15/hey-scripting-guy-march-15-2010.aspx?Redirected=true) are started with `Start-Job`.